# Accessing sharepoint site in python with windows authentication

Tags: python, authentication, sharepoint, python-requests

I am trying to work with a sharepoint site that use my windows authentication. I can use the `requests` module to access the site but it requires I explicitly state my windows password.

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

SITE = "https://sharepointsite.com/"
PASSWORD = "pw"
USERNAME = "domain\\user"

response = requests.get(SITE, auth=HttpNtlmAuth(USERNAME,PASSWORD))
print response.status_code
```

Is there a way for Python to access the site through windows authentication so I don't have to provide my password? It seems like this might be possible through `requests_nltm` but I can't work out how.

Comment: I think that the responders below don't understand that "windows authentication" means that want the Sharepoint server to pick up the authentication from the windows workstation that you are currently using.

Comment: Hey Tim, Did you get any solution on that? Please post it if you have. I tried below solution but all are giving 401 status code.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to explicitly state your windows password you could use the [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) module:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
import getpass

SITE = "https://sharepointsite.com/"
USERNAME = "domain\\user"

response = requests.get(SITE, auth=HttpNtlmAuth(USERNAME, getpass.getpass()))
print response.status_code
```

This way you don't have to store you password in plain text.

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm/blob/master/requests_ntlm/requests_ntlm.py) for the `requests_ntlm` there isn't a way to use it without supplying your password or the hash of your password to `HttpNtlmAuth`

Comment: OK - thank you. I was hoping to have this run without my intervention but guess that might not be possible if I don't want the password stored in plain text.

Comment: It may be possible, i just don't know how.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer still uses a stored password. An option to use integrated authentication via the Windows SSPI interface would be the following:

```
import requests
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth

cert = 'path\to\certificate.cer'
 
response = requests.get(
    r'http://mysharepoint.com/_api',
    auth=HttpNegotiateAuth(),
    verify=cert)

print(response.status_code)
```

See [here](https://qurios-it.de/2020/10/16/connecting-to-sharepoint-using-python/) for more information.

Answer (score -3):

Have you considered storing your username and password as environmental variable on the machine that is running the script?  This will prevent you from having to store the sensitive information within the script itself.  Then only the machine's admin can access/modify the sensitive information.

Through `cmd prompt`, set the desired variables (below syntax is for a Windows machine):

```
SET username=domain\\user
SET password=your_password
```

To ensure you've correctly set the variables, type `SET` into the `cmd prompt` and see if the variables are listed.

Once correctly set, then use python's `os` module to access the variables and use as desired:

```
import os
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

username = os.environ.get('username')
password = os.environ.get('password')

SITE = "https://sharepointsite.com/"

response = requests.get(SITE, auth=HttpNtlmAuth(username, password))
```

IMPORTANT NOTES:

1. If you close the `cmd prompt` window, the environment variables you just set will be erased and your script will throw a "I can't find environment variables" error.  To avoid this, either always keep the `cmd` window open while the script runs, or permanently set the environment variables (instructions [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) for Windows machines.  Note: the instructions refer to changing the `PATH` environment variable but you'll get the idea on how to create/modify your own variables).
2. Be careful not to overwrite an existing environment variable. First double check that a name is available by listing all variables (type `SET` into `cmd prompt`).
3. Environment variables are stored as string

Comment: On Windows systems environment variables are not very secure.  anyone can view anyone else's environment variables as they're stuck in the systemwide registry.  It's not really a good idea to put passwords or other sensitive info there.