# I'm getting a 401: Unauthorized error while trying to open an excel file from a secure Sharepoint site using packages that are native to Python

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint, python-requests

I've tried using `urllib`, `urllib2`, `requests`, and `pandas`. While my username is authorized to view the sharepoint page, I can't just load the excel files stored on sharepoint through Python. Here is the most successful code I have so far-

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
file = 'http://teamsites.teamworks.company.net/sites/company-location/RHEL-2018.51-OS-PTS-export.xlsx'

username = 'username'
password = 'password'

resp=requests.get(file, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
output = open('test.xlsx', 'wb')
output.write(resp.content)
output.close()
```

After doing this I can actually get around the 401 Unauthorized error and it makes an excel file. Now when I do `df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')` I get this error-

`XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '401 UNAU'`

Hence, still haven't gotten around the error because now it is just stored in the excel file. I open the Excel file and the only thing in there is `1: 401 UNAUTHORIZED`.

Yippe skippy. Please help, thank you!

EDIT: I have to use my windows auth to get in but I have to use **native python packages**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing sharepoint site in python with windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764595/accessing-sharepoint-site-in-python-with-windows-authentication)

Comment: i would tend to "related", not "duplicate", helpful?

Comment: That is exactly what I need but `requests_ntlm` is not native to Python and my company has a lot of red tape to get around which can take days or even week. Definitely related and the question is worded a lot better though.