# What options are there to connect to SharePoint lists if direct connection from Python isn't allowed

Tags: python, sharepoint

I have to consolidate multiple SharePoint lists into one data source for a report. This has to be done on a daily basis. At the moment, I'm handling this with:

1. Connect to SharePoint lists from Excel
2. Use Python to refresh the Excel-SharePoint connections
3. Read refreshed data and consolidate into one source with pandas

It's taking really long for the refreshing step to be done (ie. 20 mins on my machine which has 32GB RAM and 50 mins on my co-worker machine which only has 12GB).

I looked at connecting to SharePoint directly with the `sharepoint` package but I keep getting this error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='sharepoint.xxx.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

What other options do I have to improve the time it takes to get data from SharePoint lists?

Comment: SharePoint has a well documented HTTP API. The error complains about TLS and certificates, not direct access.

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos how do I go about resolving the issue with TLS and certificates? In my workplace, Sharepoint is managed by a central team and we have no admin access. Is there a certificate that I can request for window auth?

Comment: Ask *them* to fix this. It's their certificate that's causing the error. If you open a SharePoint page and click on the lock icon you should see what's wrong too - perhaps the certificate is expired? It's a self-signed certificate? It's an AD-issued certificate but your machine is not joined to that domain? Perhaps you should trust that certificate? Or (bad idea) turn off certificate validation?

Comment: Excel uses the same technologies to connect by the way. SharePoint isn't a database and lists aren't tables, so Excel has to use the same APIs in the end to get the data.

Comment: SharePoint [uses OData to allow clients to query it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests), so you don't need an extra package either. Using OData is actually simpler and quite possibly 100x faster than a package that may load entire lists at a time before iterating them. You can use packages like [pyodata](https://pypi.org/project/pyodata/) to make writing the queries easier

Comment: There isn't any certificate issue I can see when opening the SharePoint page on browser. I'm using the snippet from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764595/accessing-sharepoint-site-in-python-with-windows-authentication. Should I include some kind of certificate file in the request?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you connect. The error says that certificate verification failed. It could also be because the server uses eg SSLv3 instead of TLS, but the error complains about the specific step that failed. What SharePoint version are you trying to connect to? What OS? What is the client OS? All supported Windows versions have disabled SSLv3, and the recommended version for all applications is TLSv1.2

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a Sharepoint 2010 instance. I'm using Window 7. I'm not sure what server OS that SharePoint 2010 is running on. I have no problems with connecting to sharepoint with Excel or Access.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for your response earlier. So I actually found a certificate that works and get a code 200 response from the server. However, when I try requesting, with anything with '/_api' it redirects me to a 404 Forbidden page which looks like it was put there by my IT department. I'm not sure if that means REST API is blocked. What would you suggest to do? Should I try web scraping the response content?

Answer (score 0):

You may try `HttpNtlmAuth`:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
import getpass

username= 'YourDomain\\your_user'
response = requests.get(url_site, auth=HttpNtlmAuth(username, getpass.getpass()))
```

From then on, you can manipulate your `response` object.

Note: The `getpass` asks for a password on runtime, you may use a saved password string, but it may not be advisable for security reasons.